# Retrieve USER GRANTS of a user on ORACLE DB 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I have to drop a USER and I need to retrieve all the grants I gave to that user.

I tried querying USER_TAB_PRIVS but I saw something missing such as grant on external table or on creating synonym.

Anyone can give me an hint on how to retrieve the complete list of a grants?

I mean grants on object, table and other kind of resources?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`DBA_TAB_PRIVS -` which users/roles are granted which object privileges (select on user2.table)

`DBA_SYS_PRIVS -` which users/roles are granted which system privileges 
            (create session, drop any table, etc)

`DBA_ROLES     -` which users/roles are granted which roles

Comment: DBA_TAB_PRIVS table helped me to get the relevant details. Thanks! @kerby82 please accept this answer if above solution helped you.